# How to turn off information messages in Apache CXF dynamic client?

Tags: java, cxf

I made a dynamic client in java using Apache CXF. It works well and does all the things it is supposed to.

The one thing that is annoying me a bit, is that every time I start the program, it floods the console with information messages.

So I am wondering if it is possible to turn these off somehow? If no then I will just have to live with it.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I have to admit that I never used CXF.

Judging from the [dependencies](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/a-simple-jax-ws-service.html) CXF uses [Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/) for logging. You should head there in order to find out how to do this. Most commonly this involves finding out who logs what and then raising the log level of those classes to something like `ERROR` or `NONE`.

Comment: I set the system property like described in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436761/turn-off-apache-common-logging. Most of the messages are now gone but some still remain. What else could I do to get rid of the remainig ones?

Comment: Well... _I did something and something works but not everything_ is a bit hard to debug. As I said, I know no specifics but this shouldn't be too hard a problem.