# How to prevent cxf logging?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cxf

I want to disable logging of `org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault`.
So I found I have to create a folder `/META-INF/cxf` with file `org.apache.cxf.Logger`.

BUT what do I have to put in there to set cxf logging level to NONE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may need to comment below code in your `cxf` configuration `xml` file.

```
    <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:features>
            <cxf:logging/>
        </cxf:features>
    </cxf:bus>
```

Comment: Ok, but what do I have to set the content of the Logger file??

Comment: Logger file?, If you are creating new Logger file, it's not needed, if it's existing one please show the code. check these threads: [Turn Off Apache Common Logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436761/turn-off-apache-common-logging), [how to disable CXF logging](http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/how-to-disable-CXF-logging-td3230531.html)

Comment: No I have no existing one. And setting the system property did not work either.