# How to disable Spring logging DEBUG messages?

Tags: java, spring, log4j, slf4j, apache-commons-logging

I'm working on a simple desktop app (not webapp).

Here is my `log4j.properties`:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c{2}:%L $$$$ %m%n

log4j.logger.org.springframework=ERROR,stdout
```

As you can see, in order to eliminate Spring logging messages from the console, I tried this solution:

[Disabling Spring log, to have readable logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648014/disabling-spring-log-to-have-readable-logs)

When I call log4j logger from my code, the logging messages are according to the pattern specified above (which is good).

However, the bad part is - I still get to the console DEBUG level messages from spring... they look like here:
[Unable to disable logging messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957422/unable-to-disable-logging-messages)

And they have a different pattern. As if they ignore my settings.

I also tried to apply the suggestions I've found here:

https://spring.io/blog/2009/12/04/logging-dependencies-in-spring

In my pom file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And no SLF4J. This option was mentioned in the above link as a valid option, if I am not wrong.

What might I be missing here?

**OUTPUT with -Dlog4j.debug=true**

```
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@172aa3f.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@172aa3f class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@172aa3f.
log4j: Using URL [file:/C:/eclipse-workspace/workflow/target/classes/log4j.properties] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Reading configuration from URL file:/C:/eclipse-workspace/workflow/target/classes/log4j.properties
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[INFO, stdout].
log4j: Level token is [INFO].
log4j: Category root set to INFO
log4j: Parsing appender named "stdout".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "stdout".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c{2}:%L $$$$ %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "stdout".
log4j: Parsed "stdout" options.
log4j: Parsing for [org.springframework] with value=[ERROR,stdout].
log4j: Level token is [ERROR].
log4j: Category org.springframework set to ERROR
log4j: Parsing appender named "stdout".
log4j: Appender "stdout" was already parsed.
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.org.springframework=[null]
log4j: Finished configuring.
23:12:42.763 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initializing new StandardEnvironment
23:12:42.768 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
23:12:42.769 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
23:12:42.769 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
23:12:42.772 [main] INFO  o.s.c.s.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@7badec: startup date [Thu Feb 13 23:12:42 EST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
23:12:42.809 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initializing new StandardEnvironment
23:12:42.810 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
23:12:42.810 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
23:12:42.810 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
23:12:42.819 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-module.xml]
23:12:42.832 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader - Using JAXP provider [com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl]
23:12:42.852 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver - Loading schema mappings from [META-INF/spring.schemas]
23:12:42.857 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver - Loaded schema mappings: {http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.0.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd=schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/parameterized-types=schemas/configuration/parameterized-types.xsd, http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd=schemas/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.1.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-2.0.1.xsd, http://www.w3.org/2006/07/ws-policy.xsd=schemas/ws-policy-200607.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/oxm/config/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.2.xsd, http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing=schemas/wsdl/addressing.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.0.xsd, http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd=schemas/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.1.xsd, http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/=schemas/wsdl/wsdl.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd=org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd=org/springframework/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.1.xsd, http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/=schemas/wsdl/http.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.1.xsd, http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd=schemas/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/parameterized-types.xsd=schemas/configuration/parameterized-types.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.4.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-2.0.4.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.1.xsd, http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/2003-02-11.xsd=schemas/wsdl/wsdl.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-2.5.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/ws/addressing.xsd=schemas/ws-addr-conf.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/wsdl/http-conf.xsd=schemas/wsdl/http-conf.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.2.xsd, http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd=schemas/xml.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm.xsd=org/springframework/oxm/config/spring-oxm-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.2.xsd, http://www.w3.org/2007/02/ws-policy.xsd=schemas/ws-policy-200702.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.0.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/policy.xsd=schemas/policy.xsd, http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy/ws-policy.xsd=schemas/ws-policy-200409.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/oxm/config/spring-oxm-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-3.1.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/cxf-beans.xsd=schemas/configuration/cxf-beans.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.0.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd=schemas/core.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.0.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/security.xsd=schemas/configuration/security.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.2.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/soap.xsd=schemas/configuration/soap.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.2.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-2.0.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.5.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd=schemas/jaxws.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/oxm/config/spring-oxm-3.1.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/simple.xsd=schemas/simple.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.2.xsd}
23:12:42.858 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver - Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
23:12:42.890 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.x.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader - Loading bean definitions
23:12:42.898 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [database/spring-datasource.xml]
23:12:42.899 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader - Using JAXP provider [com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl]
23:12:42.901 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver - Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
23:12:42.911 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.x.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader - Loading bean definitions
.......................
```

**Output with -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.diagnostics.dest=STDOUT**

```
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@26290774] [ENV] Extension directories (java.ext.dir): null
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@26290774] [ENV] Application classpath (java.class.path): C:\eclipse-workspace\workflow\target\classes;C:\eclipse-workspace\idm-authentication-service\target\classes;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\com\ln\idm\product\idm-product-service\1.0-SNAPSHOT\idm-product-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\com\ln\idm\service\idm-service\1.0-SNAPSHOT\idm-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\com\ln\idm\domain\idm-internal-api\1.0-SNAPSHOT\idm-internal-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\apache\cxf\cxf-rt-databinding-xmlbeans\2.7.6\cxf-rt-databinding-xmlbeans-2.7.6.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\apache\cxf\cxf-api\2.7.6\cxf-api-2.7.6.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\woodstox\woodstox-core-asl\4.2.0\woodstox-core-asl-4.2.0.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\wsdl4j\wsdl4j\1.6.3\wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlbeans\xmlbeans\2.6.0\xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\apache\cxf\cxf-rt-core\2.7.6\cxf-rt-core-2.7.6.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.6\jaxb-impl-2.2.6.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\xmlschema\xmlschema-core\2.0.3\xmlschema-core-2.0.3.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec\1.7.1\geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.7.1.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\apache\cxf\cxf-rt-frontend-simple\2.7.6\cxf-rt-frontend-simple-2.7.6.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\apache\cxf\cxf-rt-bindings-soap\2.7.6\cxf-rt-bindings-soap-2.7.6.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\apache\cxf\cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb\2.7.6\cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-2.7.6.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\apache\cxf\cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws\2.7.6\cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.6.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\xml-resolver\xml-resolver\1.2\xml-resolver-1.2.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\asm\asm\3.3.1\asm-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\apache\cxf\cxf-rt-bindings-xml\2.7.6\cxf-rt-bindings-xml-2.7.6.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\apache\cxf\cxf-rt-ws-addr\2.7.6\cxf-rt-ws-addr-2.7.6.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\apache\cxf\cxf-rt-ws-policy\2.7.6\cxf-rt-ws-policy-2.7.6.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\apache\neethi\neethi\3.0.2\neethi-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\apache\cxf\cxf-rt-transports-http\2.7.6\cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.6.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\woodstox\woodstox-core-lgpl\4.2.0\woodstox-core-lgpl-4.2.0.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\javax\xml\stream\stax-api\1.0-2\stax-api-1.0-2.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\woodstox\stax2-api\3.1.1\stax2-api-3.1.1.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\apache\cxf\cxf-rt-ws-security\2.7.6\cxf-rt-ws-security-2.7.6.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\net\sf\ehcache\ehcache-core\2.5.1\ehcache-core-2.5.1.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\security\wss4j\1.5.8\wss4j-1.5.8.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\apache\santuario\xmlsec\1.4.3\xmlsec-1.4.3.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.1\xalan-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\xalan\serializer\2.7.1\serializer-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.0.b2\xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\3.2.4.RELEASE\spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\3.2.4.RELEASE\spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\3.2.4.RELEASE\spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\3.2.4.RELEASE\spring-orm-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-oxm\3.2.4.RELEASE\spring-oxm-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-test\3.2.4.RELEASE\spring-test-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-mock\2.0.8\spring-mock-2.0.8.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-support\2.0.8\spring-support-2.0.8.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\3.2.4.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\3.2.4.RELEASE\spring-aspects-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.7.2\aspectjweaver-1.7.2.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context-support\3.2.4.RELEASE\spring-context-support-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\apache\xbean\xbean-spring\2.8\xbean-spring-2.8.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\3.1.4.RELEASE\spring-security-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\3.1.4.RELEASE\spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\3.1.4.RELEASE\spring-security-config-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-taglibs\3.1.4.RELEASE\spring-security-taglibs-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-acl\3.1.4.RELEASE\spring-security-acl-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\com\jhlabs\imaging\BLS\imaging-BLS.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\commons-configuration\commons-configuration\1.6\commons-configuration-1.6.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.1\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\commons-digester\commons-digester\1.8\commons-digester-1.8.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.7.0\commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils-core\1.8.0\commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.3\commons-lang-2.3.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.5\slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\mockito\mockito-core\1.9.5\mockito-core-1.9.5.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.1\hamcrest-core-1.1.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\objenesis\objenesis\2.1\objenesis-2.1.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-library\1.3\hamcrest-library-1.3.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\jaxen\jaxen\1.1.4\jaxen-1.1.4.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\springmodules\spring-modules-jakarta-commons\0.8\spring-modules-jakarta-commons-0.8.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\commons-validator\commons-validator\1.1.4\commons-validator-1.1.4.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\commons-chain\commons-chain\1.1\commons-chain-1.1.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\javax\portlet\portlet-api\1.0\portlet-api-1.0.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\myfaces\myfaces-api\1.1.0\myfaces-api-1.1.0.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.3\commons-codec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\commons-el\commons-el\1.0\commons-el-1.0.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\commons-fileupload\commons-fileupload\1.0\commons-fileupload-1.0.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\oro\oro\2.0.8\oro-2.0.8.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\jstl\1.1.2\jstl-1.1.2.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.5\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.5.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.5\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.5.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.0.13\logback-classic-1.0.13.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.0.13\logback-core-1.0.13.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-access\1.0.13\logback-access-1.0.13.jar;C:\eclipse-workspace\idm-verification-service\target\classes;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.4\junit-4.4.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\ca\grimoire\log-annotations\1.0\log-annotations-1.0.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjrt\1.6.9\aspectjrt-1.6.9.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\3.2.0.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\3.2.0.RELEASE\spring-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\3.2.0.RELEASE\spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\3.2.0.RELEASE\spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\3.2.0.RELEASE\spring-expression-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\5.1.9\mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\16.0.1\guava-16.0.1.jar;C:\Users\jsmith\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.2.1\commons-lang3-3.2.1.jar
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@26290774] [ENV] Class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory was loaded via classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@26290774
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@26290774] [ENV] Ancestry of classloader which loaded org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory is sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@26290774 == 'sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1912a56'
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@26290774] [ENV] Ancestry of classloader which loaded org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory is ClassLoader tree:sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@26290774 (SYSTEM)  --> sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@24291903 --> BOOT
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@26290774] BOOTSTRAP COMPLETED
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@26290774] [LOOKUP] LogFactory implementation requested for the first time for context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@26290774
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@26290774] [LOOKUP] sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@26290774 == 'sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1912a56'
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@26290774] [LOOKUP] ClassLoader tree:sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@26290774 (SYSTEM)  --> sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@24291903 --> BOOT
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@26290774] [LOOKUP] No properties file of name 'commons-logging.properties' found.
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@26290774] [LOOKUP] Looking for system property [org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory] to define the LogFactory subclass to use...
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@26290774] [LOOKUP] No system property [org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory] defined.
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@26290774] [LOOKUP] Looking for a resource file of name [META-INF/services/org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory] to define the LogFactory subclass to use...
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@26290774] [LOOKUP]  Creating an instance of LogFactory class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory as specified by file 'META-INF/services/org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory' which was present in the path of the context classloader.
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@26290774] Loaded class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory from classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@26290774
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@26290774] Created object org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory@14185653 to manage classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@26290774
09:55:35.705 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initializing new StandardEnvironment
09:55:35.710 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
09:55:35.711 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
09:55:35.711 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
09:55:35.714 [main] INFO  o.s.c.s.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1d7999e: startup date [Fri Feb 14 09:55:35 EST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Spring uses `commons-logging` which auto-detects the logging framework to use. There are various ways to [tune which logging framework](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/guide.html#Configuration) will be chosen so the first thing to do is to make sure `commons-logging` binds to log4j.

To do that, start your application with an additional flag `-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.diagnostics.dest=STDOUT` that will output the result of the discovery process.

### commons-logging delegate to log4j

You now need to make sure that log4j is initialise with the expected configuration. By default, log4j searches for a `log4j.xml` file at the root of the classpath and fallbacks to `log4j.properties` if it does not find one. It could be possible that one of the library you are using has (wrongly) a `log4j.xml` file at the root.

To debug log4j, run your application again with an additional flag `-Dlog4j.debug=true`. This will output the exact loggers and the location of the configuration file.

### commons-logging does not delegate to log4j

If `commons-logging` does not delegate to log4j, this means that another logging framework is involved. The most common scenario is that your application ships with `jcl-over-slf4j.jar`, a [drop-in replacement](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) of `commons-logging` that uses `slf4j` behind the scene.

In this scenario, Spring uses `commons-logging` that is configured to delegate to `slf4j`. So, essentially, Spring is using `slf4j`. But [slf4j is a simple logging facade](http://www.slf4j.org/) and needs [a binding](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) to an actual framework.

> SINCE 1.6.0 If no binding is found on the class path, then SLF4J will default to a no-operation implementation.

Once you have found the binding library (it could be `logback` or `log4j` for instance), check the configuration of the logging framework that `slf4j` is bound to.

In this particular case, you probably have `logback` in your classpath. As it is a pure implementation of `slf4j`, it does not need a binding library and it logs in debug if no configuration file is provided, which matches your problem actually. To fix your issue, exclude logback from your dependencies and add `slf4j-log4j12` to configure slf4j with log4j.

---

*Edit*: updated with various comments

Comment: Thanks. It seems that `commons-logging` is bootstrapping to another logging framework than log4j. To figure out what is going on, please start your app again with `-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.diagnostics.dest=STDOUT`

Comment: Thanks... I just updated the output with `-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.diagnostics.dest=STDOUT`. What in the output I previously posted made you think `commons-logging` is using another logging framework?

Comment: So you are actually using SLF4J, see the end of the output `org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory`. This is coming from a jar called jcl-over-slf4j-X.Y.Z.jar. This confirms that the log Spring emits does *not* use log4j but are being redirected to `sl4j`. The next task is to figure out which binding is used in your classpath (see a jar starting with `slf4j-`). You should have something like `slf4j-log4j12.jar` to fix this issue. I'll edit my answer if you confirm this works for you

Comment: My question was referring to the 1st output you asked for (-Dlog4j.debug=true). Anything specific that made you think "It seems that `commons-logging` is bootstrapping to another logging framework than log4j." - or just the absence of other info from the output?
I do not have SLF4J in my pom.xml, but I depend on other projects (which I cannot change) that seem to depend on SLF4J, which is why I see in my maven dependencies (`mvn dependency:resolve`) the following jars: 
slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar, jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.5.jar, jul-to-slf4j-1.7.5.jar; as well as commons-logging-1.1.1.jar.

Comment: In my own project (which as I said uses Spring) I would prefer to use SLF4J (ideally on top op log4j). How can I tell Spring's commons-logging pick SLF4J at runtime?

Comment: Some confusions here. Spring *is* using slf4j because `jcl-over-slf4j` redirects `commons-logging` calls to slf4j. slf4j is a simple facade in front of the actual logging framework, not a logging framework by itself. Looking at the dependencies you mention,  you also redirect the `java.util` Logging API (JUL). What I don't understand at this point is that you don't have any binding in your list. Read http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html

Comment: Java needs a logging specification, this is chaos.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll In my case, commons-logging delegates to log4j1.2-API which delegates directly to log4j-core. Here, the code to check the log level is skipped and the event is directly sent to the appender. Hence, the log file is written with "debug/trace" logs even if the root logger is set to "error".

Answer (score 2):

You can disable all debug logs by just calling the below code at start of your application. And you can enable or disable at any point of time by setting log type.

```
ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger logger = (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
logger.setLevel(Level.toLevel("error"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable `commons-logging` from the dependency in `pom.xml` file of the web app.

Even after removing `commons-logging` from `pom.xml` please check the dependency hierarchy available in Eclipse or STS IDE. This will help in knowing if somehow its getting added because of some other dependency which we may not be knowing.