# Disabling debug spring logs for console

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I want to get rid off DEBUG logs of spring for console.What I have done yet:

```
  log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold=INFO
```

I have set

```
  rootLogger to INFO level
```

But still I am getting these spring debug logs.How to get rid of this?

Comment: Can you paste your entire log4j configuration? There could be other configuration that could be overriding your setting.

Comment: Please [check this answer first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739578/how-to-disable-spring-logging-debug-messages/21748252#21748252)

Comment: I have already chkd these soltns.. anywayz my problem has been fixed bt no proper ans why and hw it gt fixed..