# Spring 4, JPA, Turn off console debug messages

Tags: spring, jpa, configuration

I have a basic Spring 4 JPA application. I use all Java configurations (no XML at all). I want to turn off the console debug messages. I have seen many questions on this and tried the solutions but still I see all the messages.

The console messages look like this:

```
14:58:29.301 [main] DEBUG o.h.loader.entity.plan.EntityLoader....
14:58:29.328 [main] INFO  o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate....
....
14:58:29.905 [main] DEBUG o.h.h.i.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl - --- HQL AST ---
    \-[QUERY] Node: 'query'
      \-[SELECT_FROM] Node: 'SELECT_FROM'
      +-[FROM] Node: 'from'
       |  \-[RANGE] Node: 'RANGE'
       |     +-[DOT] Node: '.'
       |     |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'hello'
       |     |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'Customer'
       |     \-[ALIAS] Node: 'generatedAlias0'
    \-[SELECT] Node: 'select'
     \-[IDENT] Node: 'generatedAlias0'
....
Hundreds of lines more....
```

I tried to set show_sql both in the HibernateJpaVendorAdapter and in the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean as shown below:

```
@Bean
  public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() throws SQLException {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
    vendorAdapter.setShowSql(false);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan("hello");
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());

    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
    jpaProperties.put( "hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" );
    jpaProperties.put( "hibernate.show_sql", false );
    jpaProperties.put( "show_sql", false );
    jpaProperties.put( "hibernate.generate_statistics", false );
    factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factory.getObject();
  }
```

Thank you for any ideas on this!

**-- Edit -- more info**

What I do is create a Spring Starter Project with Spring Tools Suite and just select JPA. I then add MySQL to my pom.xml.

As a test I have a basic Customer and CustomerRepository class and the JPA configuration I noted above.

My Application class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    AbstractApplicationContext context = new
      AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(JPAConfiguration.class);

      CustomerRepository repository = context.getBean(CustomerRepository.class);

      //use the repository.....

      ((AbstractApplicationContext) context).close();
      context.close();
  }
}
```

So that is it -- a very basic JPA Spring Starter Project created with Spring Tools Suite. If I could figure out how to deal with logging in that I could translate that info to my actual project.

**-- Edit -- even more info -- and it's fixed!**

OK this is interesting...
I changed my Application class and the problem goes away.
So using the this Application (vs. the one posted above) and the logging problem is now OK -- anyone who could comment why this works like this?

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ConfigurableApplicationContext context =
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class);

    CustomerRepository repository = context.getBean(CustomerRepository.class);

    //use the repository.....

    context.close();
  }
}
```

Note the solution provided below by Alan Hay also works great regardless of how I do the Application class!

Note with either way you can still set setJpaProperties as shown my configuration (see Bean above) to control if you want to see Hibernate's SQL, etc.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739578/how-to-disable-spring-logging-debug-messages/21748252#21748252)

Comment: You need to change Hibernate logging level

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I encountered the same issue recently. It appears Spring 4 uses the logback library for logging and my app only had a log4j config file. Adding an additional logging configuration file for logback  solved the issue.

If you have an existing log4j config file there is a tool to convert this to logback format here:

http://logback.qos.ch/translator/

If not try adding a file named logback.xml to the root of your classpath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                                                              
<configuration>
  <appender name="A1" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <logger name="org.springframework" level="ERROR"/>
  <logger name="org.hibernate" level="ERROR"/>
  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="A1"/>
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This worked great! Is there a way to do it without XML (so like the same way I configured Hibernate in my above example)? Also see edited info I posted above about another way I got it to work.

Comment: Quick note: I found that this pattern worked best for my JPA applciation: <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>