# Disable springframework logging

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, logging, log4j

I want to disable console logging messages spawned by org.springframework.* stuff. My log4j.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC
  "-//APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN"
  "http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
          <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p  [%c{1}] %m %n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework">
        <level value="off" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.myapp">
        <level value="all" />
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
    </logger>

</log4j:configuration>
```

But it doesn't work. I still see a lot of DEBUG, INFO messages produces by org.springframework on my console.

What should I change to make it works?

Comment: If you are using Spring 4 it uses Logback rather than Log4J. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23595045/1356423

Comment: Correct, everything works after I put logback.xml to /src/main/resources/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring 4, JPA, Turn off console debug messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23572274/spring-4-jpa-turn-off-console-debug-messages)

Answer (score 1):

Spring will use the debug level- to get rid of it change the level of Spring to be Info:

```
<logger name="org.springframework">
    <level value="Info" />
    <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
</logger>
```

Edit: Should you not want any Info logs either change the value to be

```
<level value="Warn" />
```

Also I see you have specified level value="off" - change this to be Trace, having it off will mean you wont see exceptions

Comment: Please look carefully, I already have the same lines for "org.springframework" logger in abovementioned log4j.xml. It doesn't work for me.

Comment: you have the level specified as off

Comment: and so what? Level OFF also surpasses DEBUG messages like INFO or WARN. Can't get your point.

Comment: Apologies I somehow managed to not also put in the appender ref when I pasted the config! As best practise I wouldn't turn all logging off for catching exceptions

Answer (score 1):

Springframework logging will not get removed till `commons-logging` is present in dependency.

You have to disable `commons-logging` from the dependency in pom.xml file of the web app.

Even after removing `commons-logging` from pom.xml please check the dependency hierarchy available in Eclipse or STS IDE. This will help in knowing if somehow its getting added because of some other dependency management which we may not be knowing.

After removing dependency just add `log4j.logger.org.springframework=ERROR` to your log4j configuration. This will help.

Answer (score 0):

1 add `<appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>` to org.springframework logger

2 make sure log4j.jar and log4j.xml are on the classpath

Comment: Tried with and without appender. log4j.xml placed in /src/main/resources/log4j.xml - standard maven directory layout. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Add JCL over SLF4J dependency to redirect logs from commons-logging to SLF4J:

```
    <jcl.over.slf4j.version>1.7.13</jcl.over.slf4j.version>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${jcl.over.slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```