# turning off spring debug logs

Tags: spring, log4j, slf4j, apache-commons-logging

I am using log4j for logging to console as well as file.Setting the threshold to INFO level  doesn't prevents debug logs from spring.I have set rootlogger to INFO level as well.

I guess my spring logs are coming from my dependencies.M not able to get rid of them by setting level OFF for spring logs as well.Spring logs are using commons logging.How can I turn off these logs in my XML file?

Comment: works fine for me, care to share the logs and log configuration?

Comment: Can you check [if this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739578/how-to-disable-spring-logging-debug-messages/21748252#21748252) solves your problem?