# How to turn off slf4j logging

Tags: java, debugging, logging, slf4j

I'm using third par .jar files in my project. 
When I start my application my standard output is full of log messages.
I try to show some informaion to user, but now it's impossible.
How can I disable logging?

Answer (score 0):

This is too generic question. Please be specific about the log message you want to suppress.

SLF4J implementations have configuration to turn off debug messages e.g. log4j2.xml uses  property for setting logging level. Many frameworks like spring/hibernate/jersey have the setting available to set the logging level. Here are few links

[Disabling Spring logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739578/how-to-disable-spring-logging-debug-messages)

[Disabling hibernate logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311408/turning-off-hibernate-logging-console-output)