# Disable debug logging from Java AWS S3 client with Junit tests

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, logging

I having a JUnit gradle project that uses the Java AWS s3 client.

```
compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-s3', version: '1.11.707'
compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-sts', version: '1.11.707'
```

Since adding this client I am getting tons of log message from org.apache.http classes.  I cannot figure out how to disable them.

My tests use logback.  Here is my config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>


    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <logger name="guru.springframework.controllers" level="WARN" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="guru.springframework.helpers" level="WARN" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.jayway.jsonpath" level="INFO"/>
    <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.NopStatusListener" />

    <logger name="org.apache.zookeeper" level="OFF"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.kafka" level="OFF"/>
    <logger name="ch.qos.logback" level="OFF"/>

    <logger name="org.apache" level="ERROR" />
    <logger name="httpclient" level="ERROR" />

 </configuration>
```

There are a variety of posts around that suggest ways to solve this, none of which have worked for me.  Here is an example of one:

[Turn Off Apache Common Logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436761/turn-off-apache-common-logging)

With a Junit test I have no main() and I don't know if there is a similar place to put something like:

```
 System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log",
                         "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");
```

Here is another idea that doesn't work for me:

[Disable HttpClient logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915414/disable-httpclient-logging)

Having these lines in my logback config doesn't see to do anything:

```
    <logger name="org.apache" level="ERROR" />
    <logger name="httpclient" level="ERROR" />
```

Answer (score 1):

My issue was the fact that I only had a

```
main/resources/logback-spring.xml
```

What I needed was a:

```
test/resources/logback-test.xml
```

I am assuming that I needed this because one of my dependencies has a logback-test.xml that was being used instead of my main/resources/logback-spring.xml.